# Is there any wrapper for gecko in gtk#

Tags: c#

Is there any wrapper for gecko in gtk#? I couldn't find any, despite I could find a wrapper for WinForms, which apparently aren't useable cross plaform. (They can be compiled cross platform, but my experience with WinForm in linux is more than horrible)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's Gecko# which works with GTK# The Novell mono site has a nice little example (It's a tad outdated, but should still be relevant)

[Cool Solutions: Mono, Gtk#, Gecko# and the Gecko Runtime Environment on Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20190627061351/http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/14918.html)

They show the same code running on Linux and on Windows

Comment: ok, but where can I get it? the document doesn't provide any download links, and this library isn't part of current mono release